# What's coherent about coherent sheaves?

Tags: terminology, ho.history-overview, reference-request

In a recent [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44005/intuition-for-rational-functions/44040#44040) to a recent [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44005/intuition-for-rational-functions), [BCnrd](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3927/bcnrd) wrote

> [...] beyond the coherent case one cannot expect information about a fiber (e.g., vanishing, 6 generators, etc.) to "propogate" to information in a neighborhoood (which would be the spirit behind the choice of word "coherent", I suppose). [...]

Is that what motivates the adjective *coherent*? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the earliest reference is _Seminaire Ecole Normale et Superieur 1951-52 exposes XVIII et XIX_. This is given in H. Cartan, Serre _Un théorème de finitude concernant les variétés analytiques compactes_ C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris  237,  (1953). 128–130. All of this work seems to be in analytic spaces, so perhaps there is something in that area that will be a clue.

Comment: My recollection is that in the (awesome) book "Coherent analytic sheaves", the historical comments either in the Introduction or the appendix on "yoga of coherence" refer to coherence as a kind of principle of local analytic continuation.  Take a look at those parts of that book and you may find such documentation that you seek. Maybe also look at historical notes in Oka's collected works. 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the paper of MALATIAN

"Faisceaux analytiques: étude du faisceau des rélations entre p fonctions holomorphes",

Séminaire Henry Cartan, tome 4 (1951-52), exp. n.15, p. 1-10

one finds the

**Definition 3**

> "On dit qu'un sous-faisceau analytique $\mathcal{F}$ de $\mathcal{O}_E^q$ is $cohérent$ au point  $x \in E$, s'il existe un voisinage ouvert $U$ de $x$ et un système fini d'elements $u_i \in \mathcal{O}_U^q$ jouissant de la propriété suivante: pour tout $y \in U$, le sous-module de $\mathcal{O}_U^q$ engendré par les $u_i$ est précisement $\mathcal{F}_y$. 
> On dit qu'un faisceau $\mathcal{F}$ est cohérent (tout court) s'il est coherent en tout point de $E$."

And, in the following page:

> "...En d'autre termes, cette condition exprime que le faisceau $induit$ par $\mathcal{F}$ sur l'ouvert $U$ est "engendré" par un sous-module de $\mathcal{O}_U^q$."

Reading this,  it seems that the original definition given by Cartan in its seminar is somehow related to the "coherent behaviour" of $\mathcal{F}$ as a subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}_U^q$, in terms of generation of the stalks.

**EDIT.**

However, this is not the whole story. Loking at the introduction of the book of Grauert-Remmert, as Brian suggests, it appears that the word "coherent" was actually introduced by Cartan  some years before, in the middle of the '40; in fact, he investigated the so-called "coherent systems of punctual modules" when studyng the Cousin's problem. But he does not mention this previous work in his Seminar, when he introduces coherent analytic sheaves.

Grauert-Remmert write that

> "coherence is, in a vague sense, a local principle of analytic continuation".

And Cartan himself, in its collected works, says

> "En gros on peut dire que, pour en $A$-faisceaux $\mathcal{F}$ cohérent en un point $a$ de $A$, la connaissance du module $\mathcal{F}_a$ détermine les modules $\mathcal{F}_x$ attachées aux points  $x$ suffisamment voisins de $a$."